# Netty ChannelRead method is not getting invoked

Tags: netty

Hi In my netty sample if I configure my ServerBootstrap with AUTO_READ option as false. Then in my corresponding handler ChannelRead method is never getting invoked, only ChannelActive is getting invoked. However if I remove the AUTO_READ option then everything is working and both the methods are getting invoked.

Am I missing something very basic here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `AUTO_READ` is set to false, no read operation occurs until you explicitely call `channel.read();`

When you set it to true, then read are automatically allowed and passed up to the handlers.

See [here](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/Channel.html#read())